# How to get value of comment parent in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

When user reply comment of another user, I would like the replied comment to be intended. How do I get the value of comment parent and save it to the database?

```
<input name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="" type="hidden">
```

I have allowed threaded comment in wp admin, but I still get comment_parent = 0 in the database.

Below is the function I use in comments.php

```
// comment form
function wope_comment_form(){
    $post_option = get_option('wope-post');

    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );


    $fields =  array(
        'author' =>     '<div class="comment-form-left">
                            <div class="comment-form-author">' .
                            __('Your Name*','wope').' <br>
                            <input id="comment-author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . '  />' .
                        '</div>',
        'email'  =>     '<div class="comment-form-email"> '.
                            __('Your E-Mail*','wope').' <br>
                            <input id="comment-email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . ' />'
                            .'<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'comment_parent\' id=\'comment_parent\' value=\''. esc_attr($comment->comment_parent) .'\' />'
                        .'</div>',
        'url'    =>     '<div class="comment-form-url">'.
                            __('Your Webpage','wope').' <br>
                            <input id="comment-url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . ' />'.
                        '</div></div>',
    );




    $args = array(

        'fields' => $fields,
        'title_reply' => '<span>'.__( 'Leave Your Comment' , 'wope').'</span>',
        'label_submit' => __( 'Submit Your Comment' , 'wope' ),
        'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment">'                           
                                .__('Your Comment*','wope').' <br>
                                <textarea name="comment" rows="4" ></textarea>


                        </p>',
        'comment_notes_before'  => '',  

            'comment_notes_after'  => get_wpml_comment(),
            'comment_notes_before' => 'The Smilies are below.',

    );
    comment_form($args);

}
```